# Databricks SQL error: cannot evaluate expression outer in inline table definition

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I joined two tables and tried to get a max timestamp value of two timestamp fields. This is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
   rts.DataLakeModified_DateTime, 
   rtt.DataLakeModified_DateTime,
   (
     SELECT MAX(DataLakeModifiedDateTime)
     FROM VALUES(rts.DataLakeModified_DateTime), (rtt.DataLakeModified_DateTime) AS AllDates (DataLakeModifiedDateTime)
   ) AS DataLakeModifiedDateTime
FROM RetailTransactionSalesTrans_Full rts
LEFT JOIN RetailTransactionTable_Full rtt
    ON rtt.TRANSACTIONID = rts.TRANSACTIONID
        AND rtt.CHANNEL = rts.CHANNEL
        AND rtt.STORE = rts.STORE
        AND rtt.TERMINAL = rts.TERMINALID
```

But it has an error:

```
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: cannot evaluate expression outer(rts.DataLakeModified_DateTime) in inline table definition; line 6 pos 17
```

I'm using Spark3.2.1 and MSSQL database. And I'm running it on Azure Databricks notebook using 104 LTS cluster (include Apache Spark3.2.1, Scala 2.12).

Do you have any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Put your `VALUES` in a `OUTER APPLY` after the joins

Comment: @HoneyBadger, thanks for your response. Do you mean I should use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: no, though an `OUTER APPLY` is semantically similar. Take a look [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/sqlstudies.com/2013/05/20/the-many-uses-of-cross-apply/amp/), for what I mean (they use `CROSS APPLY`, which is more like an `INNER JOIM`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be because of the usage of the following SQL statement to get the maximum timestamp value.

```
SELECT MAX(DataLakeModifiedDateTime) 
     FROM VALUES(rts.DataLakeModified_DateTime), (rtt.DataLakeModified_DateTime) AS AllDates (DataLakeModifiedDateTime)
```

- I tried with 2 sample tables `tb1` and `tb2` which have timestamp fields `t1` and `t2`.The following is how the tables look.

[image]

- When I used to get maximum time stamp values using the same syntax that you used, it gave the same error.

[image]

- Instead, when I tried it using the `CASE` statement, it gave the desired output.

[image]

So, modify your SQL query as shown below:

```
SELECT  
   rts.DataLakeModified_DateTime,  
   rtt.DataLakeModified_DateTime, 
   ( 
     CASE WHEN rts.DataLakeModified_DateTime > rtt.DataLakeModified_DateTime THEN rts.DataLakeModified_DateTime ELSE rtt.DataLakeModified_DateTime END 
) AS DataLakeModifiedDateTime 
FROM RetailTransactionSalesTrans_Full rts 
LEFT JOIN RetailTransactionTable_Full rtt 
    ON rtt.TRANSACTIONID = rts.TRANSACTIONID 
        AND rtt.CHANNEL = rts.CHANNEL 
        AND rtt.STORE = rts.STORE 
        AND rtt.TERMINAL = rts.TERMINALID
```

Comment: It's working for me. thank you very much!
Also I found another solution with `GREATEST` function, simply. 
`
GREATEST(rts.DataLakeModified_DateTime, rtt.DataLakeModified_DateTime) AS DataLakeModifiedDateTime 
`
It looks like it's simply than `WHEN ... THEN ...` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution with `GREATEST` function, simply.

```
GREATEST(rts.DataLakeModified_DateTime, rtt.DataLakeModified_DateTime) AS DataLakeModifiedDateTime
```

It looks like it's simply than WHEN ... THEN ... clause.

Finally, the SQL statement is :

```
SELECT  
   rts.DataLakeModified_DateTime,  
   rtt.DataLakeModified_DateTime, 
   GREATEST(rts.DataLakeModified_DateTime, rtt.DataLakeModified_DateTime) AS DataLakeModifiedDateTime 
FROM RetailTransactionSalesTrans_Full rts 
LEFT JOIN RetailTransactionTable_Full rtt 
    ON rtt.TRANSACTIONID = rts.TRANSACTIONID 
        AND rtt.CHANNEL = rts.CHANNEL 
        AND rtt.STORE = rts.STORE 
        AND rtt.TERMINAL = rts.TERMINALID
```

It worked correctly.
Thank you!